# What we mean by determinant of a projective R- module?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

To define Euler class of a group we use the term, Let p be a projective R module of determinant L or trivial Determinant. Then my question is, what we mean by this determinant.

Answer (score 5):

Let $P$ be a projective $A$-module of rank $n$. Let $\bigwedge^n P$ denote the $n$th exterior power of $P$. Then $\bigwedge^n P$ is a projective $A$-module of rank $1$ and is called the determinant of $P$. We say the determinant of $P$ is trivial if $\bigwedge^n P \cong A$.

You may find this definition [here](https://web.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/doug/otherpapers/Kbook.I.pdf) (page 16) or [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.2643.pdf) (page 8).